# Removing gem elasticsearch-extensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, rubygems, rake

In Rails 5, I've had the following gems in my Gemfile:

- gem 'chewy'
- gem 'elasticsearch-model'
- gem 'elasticsearch-extensions'

I'm trying to remove elasticsearch from my project but after removing the **'elasticsearch-extensions'** gem, and then bundling I am getting an error each time I try and do a rake task - eg. "rails routes".

LoadError: cannot load such file -- elasticsearch/extensions/test/cluster/tasks

Any ideas what's going on and how I can fix?

Thanks heaps!

Comment: Dumb but did you remove `elasticsearch-model` as well?

Comment: Thanks, yeah I removed them all and got the problem, then tried removing them one at a time to see which one was the issue.  Removing the other two is fine but as soon as I remove the 'elasticsearch-extensions' it throws the rake error whenever i want to run a rake type task.

Comment: Did the gems have a set up setup or anything that added files to your repo? Or did you forget to remove any initializers you setup when installing these gems?